# SQL: How to make a Coalesce on each VARCHAR column after a group by?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, group-by, coalesce

Using the table below:

```
id: integer| col_1: VARCHAR| col_2: VARCHAR | col_3: VARCHAR
------------------------------------------------------------
      1    |       'a'     |       'b'      |       null 
      2    |       null    |       'b'      |       'c'
      3    |       'd'     |       'e'      |       null
      4    |       null    |       'e'      |       'f'
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
'a' | 'b' | 'c'
'd' | 'e' | 'f'
```

I tried this query:

```
SELECT colaesce(t.col_1), colaesce(t.col_2), coalesce(t.col_3)
FROM ( select * from table ) t 
INNER JOIN table ON t.col_2 = table.col_2;
```

I'm new to SQL and I would appreciate any help !

Comment: Show us your tries

Comment: @Backs `SELECT colaesce(col_1), colaesce(col_2), coalesce(col_3)
    FROM ( select * from table ) t 
    INNER JOIN table ON t.a = table.a;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this with `UNION`.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rn] = row_number() over(
        partition by t.[cols]
        order by t.[col_val]
    ), *
    from(
        select [col_1] [col_val], 'col_1' [cols]
        from [your_table_name]
        where [col_1] is not null
        union
        select [col_2], 'col_2'
        from [your_table_name]
        where [col_2] is not null
        union
        select [col_3], 'col_3'
        from [your_table_name]
        where [col_3] is not null
    )t
)
select 
max(case [cols] when 'col_1' then [col_val] end) [col_1],
max(case [cols] when 'col_2' then [col_val] end) [col_2],
max(case [cols] when 'col_3' then [col_val] end) [col_3]
from cte
group by [rn];
```

**[Find demo here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/673187/sql-how-to-make-a-coalesce-on-each-varchar-column-after-a-group-by)**

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Ullas, for this clean answer. Just to be sure I understood the querying process. First you created a pivot view of the table and then assigned to all rows with the same column name the same Id **[rn]** using the row number function. Finally you made a group by on each partition.